# Valorant Tracker.gg API

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

someone helped me with webscraping using tracker.gg's API and puppeteer but since the season change, the API returns this error message

`{"errors":[{"code":"CollectorResultStatus::InvalidParameters","message":"One of the provide parameters is invalid.","data":{}}]}`

when it used to return an array with all the data needed for the program.
Can anybody help me find the right website for the new season's statistics ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this post is old but, you can always retrieve the specific endpoints that they retrieve from their own backend systems to the frontend page you're viewing by monitoring the traffic that was requested and filtering it out by 'api' or 'tracker'.

Note that Tracker.gg is against anyone from web scraping their website for the Valorant section (and maybe other games) and may try to actively revoke you from doing so. Check their robots.txt just to be sure.

I personally have used their site to scrape data for my own project and had been booted off as a result thanks to their cloudflare 'anti-bot' detection. An example of an api endpoint I found through this method is [https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/valorant/standard/profile/riot/{userURL}?forceCollect=true](https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/valorant/standard/profile/riot/%7BuserURL%7D?forceCollect=true)